# Doctrine nested AND OR query

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony4, dql

I'm working in a DQL witch is almost ok but I need to change one 'AND' with a 'OR'... this is the query I'm getting now so far:

```
SELECT * 
FROM amp a0_ 
WHERE (a0_.expediente LIKE '%zumardia 27%' OR a0_.expediente LIKE '%zumardia__27%') AND (a0_.expediente LIKE '%apertura%' OR a0_.expediente LIKE '%apertura%') 

****AND**** (a0_.fecha LIKE '%zumardia 27%' OR a0_.fecha LIKE '%zumardia__27%') AND (a0_.fecha LIKE '%apertura%' OR a0_.fecha LIKE '%apertura%')
```

the ****AND**** is witch I need to change, this is my code right now:

```
foreach ($fields as $field) {
    foreach ($value as $v) {
        $toFind = [' ',',','?'];
        $clean = str_replace($toFind, '__', $v);

        $qb->andWhere(
            $qb->expr()->orX(
                $qb->expr()->orX($expr->like('a.'.$field, ':v'.$field.$miindex)),
                $qb->expr()->orX($expr->like('a.'.$field, ':v2'.$field.$miindex))
            )
        )->setParameter('v'.$field.$miindex, '%'.$v.'%')
        ->setParameter('v2'.$field.$miindex, '%'.$clean.'%');
    }
}
```

What I want to do is search for 2 parameters y every fields on a table

Comment: store the $qb->expr() from each loop-iteration into an array and add it as `$qb->andWhere($qb->expr()->orX($array))` outside the loop? should be able to call `setParameter` without the parameter already inside the query ...

Comment: okay, you probably need some andX after the value loop and an orX after the field loop

Comment: To offer a different approach if I may, I have struggled with something very similar in a recent project.  I hate fighting my tools and after a while such code is not clear or maintainable. I ended up using native sql for it.